# How to deploy a node.js application to heroku that lies within a subfolder of a repository

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm unsure how to deploy my web application to heroku where the actual web application is generated within a sub folder. I have the project tree:

```
app
assets
dist
server
// other stuff ....
```

now when I want to run my server & frontend, I do `gulp`. gulp creates a folder named `build` which contains all needed files for running the web app, so my file tree would become

```
app
assets
dist
server
build
// other stuff ....
```

Is there a way to initialize the heroku repository to **only** the folder `build`? Since my actual web app lies inside just that folder, it's probably easier for me to only have heroku think the build folder exists.

I currently have heroku setup with only `heroku create` inside the parent repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. What I decided to do was include my build folder into my repository (did not add much bloat, only like 50kb). Then, when I wanted to deploy to heroku I did:

```
git subtree split --prefix build -b deploy
git push heroku deploy:master
git branch -D deploy
```

this created a branch with only the build folder, pushed that to heroku (use `-f` if you need to overwrite previous commits), the deleted the deploy branch.

Worked like a charm!